# Error with deployed Matlab DLL in C# (Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds (must not exceed 1))

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, matlab-deployment

I deployed a matlab function to an .NET Assembly and now I have some problems with the implementation.

My GUI is telling me that there is an Error in my .m-file at line 12 but I dont really see the issue.
Hope you can help me out!

This is my C# Code which is using the deployed .NET Assembly (Gradient) and parts of the Mathworks API:

```
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility;
using Gradient;

namespace matlabv3
{
    public class Gradientenberechnung
    {
        public static void addNum()
        {
            int pdata = 250;

            CSharpGradient gradient = new CSharpGradient();
            MWArray output = gradient.gradientVarianteA((MWArray)pdata); //<-- Error happens here

            Console.WriteLine("Output: ", output);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

This is my Matlab function which returns the mathematical gradient:

```
function [outputArg] = gradientVarianteA(pdata)

%% Variante A - Only the maximum difference is calculated without division by the distance
    d = nan(10,9);
    for n = 1:numel(pdata)
        [j,i] = ind2sub(size(pdata),n);
        switch true
            case j==1
                if i == 1
                    d(j,i) = max(abs([...
                        NaN                         NaN                     NaN...
                        NaN                         NaN                     pdata(j,i)-pdata(j,i+1)...
                        NaN                         pdata(j,i)-pdata(j+1,i) pdata(j,i)-pdata(j+1,i+1)]));
                elseif i == 9
                    d(j,i) = max(abs([...
                        NaN                         NaN                     NaN...
                        pdata(j,i)-pdata(j,i-1)     NaN                     NaN...
                        pdata(j,i)-pdata(j+1,i-1)   pdata(j,i)-pdata(j+1,i) NaN]));
                else
                    d(j,i) = max(abs([...
                        NaN                         NaN                     NaN...
                        pdata(j,i)-pdata(j,i-1)     NaN                     pdata(j,i)-pdata(j,i+1)...
                        pdata(j,i)-pdata(j+1,i-1)   pdata(j,i)-pdata(j+1,i) pdata(j,i)-pdata(j+1,i+1)]));
                end
            case j==10
                if i == 1
                    d(j,i) = max(abs([...
                        NaN                         pdata(j,i)-pdata(j-1,i) pdata(j,i)-pdata(j-1,i+1)...
                        NaN                         NaN                     pdata(j,i)-pdata(j,i+1)...
                        NaN                         NaN                     NaN]));
                elseif i == 9
                    d(j,i) = max(abs([...
                        pdata(j,i)-pdata(j-1,i-1)   pdata(j,i)-pdata(j-1,i) NaN...
                        pdata(j,i)-pdata(j,i-1)     NaN                     NaN...
                        NaN                         NaN                     NaN]));
                else
                    d(j,i) = max(abs([...
                        pdata(j,i)-pdata(j-1,i-1)   pdata(j,i)-pdata(j-1,i) pdata(j,i)-pdata(j-1,i+1)...
                        pdata(j,i)-pdata(j,i-1)     NaN                     pdata(j,i)-pdata(j,i+1)...
                        NaN                         NaN                     NaN]));
                end
            otherwise
                if i == 1
                    d(j,i) = max(abs([...
                        NaN                         pdata(j,i)-pdata(j-1,i) pdata(j,i)-pdata(j-1,i+1)...
                        NaN                         NaN                     pdata(j,i)-pdata(j,i+1)...
                        NaN                         pdata(j,i)-pdata(j+1,i) pdata(j,i)-pdata(j+1,i+1)]));
                elseif i == 9
                    d(j,i) = max(abs([...
                        pdata(j,i)-pdata(j-1,i-1)   pdata(j,i)-pdata(j-1,i) NaN...
                        pdata(j,i)-pdata(j,i-1)     NaN                     NaN...
                        pdata(j,i)-pdata(j+1,i-1)   pdata(j,i)-pdata(j+1,i) NaN]));
                else
                    d(j,i) = max(abs([...
                        pdata(j,i)-pdata(j-1,i-1)   pdata(j,i)-pdata(j-1,i) pdata(j,i)-pdata(j-1,i+1)...
                        pdata(j,i)-pdata(j,i-1)     NaN                     pdata(j,i)-pdata(j,i+1)...
                        pdata(j,i)-pdata(j+1,i-1)   pdata(j,i)-pdata(j+1,i) pdata(j,i)-pdata(j+1,i+1)]));
                end
        end
    end

outputArg = d;
end
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @fredrik the full error msg is:
"Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds (must not exceed 1).
Error in => gradientVarianteA.m at line 12."

Comment: So it's complaining that the input you pass is too small. `pdata` is defined as an int but your function seems to expect an array.